# prove $| \cup_n A_n| <\mathfrak{c}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

If $\{A_n: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is a sequence of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $|A_n| < \mathfrak{c}$ for all $n$. Prove $| \cup_n A_n| <\mathfrak{c}$

with $\mathfrak{c}$ the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$.

I think we want to make a bijection from one $A_n$ to  $ \cup_n A_n$. Because the first has cardinality smaller than $\mathfrak{c}$, the second must have too.

Comment: Did you try anything on your own to solve the problem?

Comment: You're assuming $|A_n| = |\cup A_k|$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ which is not necessarily true if $\mathfrak{c} > 2^{\aleph_\omega}$. Assume $|A_n| = \aleph_n$, then $|\cup A_n|=\aleph{\omega}$.

Comment: @kedrigern: It is impossible that $2^{\aleph_\omega}<\frak c$. We can have, however, $\aleph_\omega<\frak c$ or $2^{\aleph_\omega}=\frak c$.

Comment: Sure, I meant $\frak{c} > \aleph_{\omega}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly if there is some $k$ such that $|A_n|\leq|A_k|$ for all $k$, then the solution you propose works just fine. However your strategy may fail. It is consistent that there are such $A_n$'s such that $|A_n|<|A_{n+1}|$, and so $\bigcup A_n$ has cardinality greater than any single $A_n$.

Suppose that is the case, and let $\kappa_n=|A_n|$, then $\kappa=\sup\kappa_n=2^{\aleph_0}=\frak c$. We have now that $\kappa^\omega>\kappa$ by Koenig's theorem, however $\frak c^\omega=c$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Ah, Koenig's theorem does it!

Comment: Question:  $| \cup_n A_n|=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathfrak{a}_n < \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathfrak{b}_n= \mathfrak{c}^k= \mathfrak{c}$, for $k \to \infty$. Is this true?

Comment: I'm not sure what are $\frak a_n,b_n$ in this notation. Moreover the cardinal exponentiation is discontinuous (usually); and $k\to\infty$ is sorta vague in the context of cardinal (and ordinal) arithmetic anyway.

Comment: Simpler: because there are possibly infinite $A_n$ shouldn't this lead to $\mathfrak{c}^\infty=\mathfrak{c}$?

Comment: What's $\frak c^\infty$?

Comment: $\mathfrak{c}*...*\mathfrak{c}*\mathfrak{c}*$ infinite times, because there are infinite $A_n$

Comment: Oh, im sorry, I was wrong. I reread your prove but it's stil not clear to me. Already in the beginning, $A_{n+1} \subset \cup A_n$ right?

Comment: Roman. It seems that you approach cardinal arithmetic as if it was calculus. There is no such thing is $\infty$ in cardinal arithmetic. We can talk about $\aleph_0$ as a limit point, and we can talk about other limit cardinals as well. But the symbol $\infty$ and the calculus notion of limit are *very* different than the ones in cardinal arithmetics, and in particular the fact that a lot of things are not continuous at limit points. So talking about $\mathfrak c^k$ where $k\to\infty$ is meaningless. However $\mathfrak c^{\aleph_0}=\frak c$, that much **is** true. But $\aleph_0\neq\infty$.